# Getting getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mongo when trying to connect to MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, docker, mongoose, docker-compose

I'm trying to connect to a mongoDB database inside a docker container but I'm getting this error message : "getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mongo" and I have no idea what caused it. I'm still new to docker and I can't seem to find a solution to this problem.

Here is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo:latest
    restart: always
    container_name: mongodb
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
    volumes:
      - mongodb:/data/db
    environment:
       MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: hazem 
       MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123  
       MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: DB 
volumes:
  mongodb: {}
```

and here is the function to connect to the DB :

```
export const connectDB = async () => {
  try {
    await mongoose.connect("mongodb://hazem:123@mongo:27017/DB");
    console.log("connected to DB");
  } catch (error: any) {
    console.log(error.message);
    // retry to connect after 5 seconds
    setTimeout(connectDB, 5000);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 5):

All I had to do was check the 'Direct connection' checkbox and it connected right away.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If your code runs on the host then the connection string should be:

```
mongodb://hazem:123@localhost:27017/DB
```

Your connection string is correct if it runs in a container, but then you need to make sure the container is on the same docker network as the database container.

Comment: I guess you are right but when I changed it to host I got at first an authentication fail, but it worked when I removed the database name("DB") from the uri can you please explain why is that? @Mihai

Comment: I don’t really know since that is MongoDB related. Maybe that’s not the way to specify the database?